# Converting R's Random Forest model to Mahout

Tags: r, random-forest

I need to implement an RF created by R on Hadoop. I know a way is to recreate the random forest with the same training data using Mahout. But is it possible to convert the RF created by R directly into a format that Mahout can use, for scoring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to use the Rattle package in R to export your Random Forest model as PMML. Then use Cascading to score with that PMML model at scale on Apache Hadoop.

Examples for just this are shown at:

```
http://www.cascading.org/pattern/
```

Code is already available in the pre-defined app. Just run that JAR shown in the example.

A presentation about this is showing at slide 48-ff in http://www.slideshare.net/pacoid/the-workflow-abstration

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly: Mahout does not do anything with PMML, no. You can't import/export from/to anything else. PMML + Cascading Pattern is a lot closer to what you seem to want.